# How to successfully Deep Link to a closed app whose target view will take time to load

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, deep-linking

I have an app in which I handle Deep Links to various navigation targets in the app.

This works fine when the app is running in the background - but if the app has been closed, the views involved in the navigation the Deep Link needs to do may take a couple of seconds to load, especially on older hardware.

Looking for a best practice on how to handle this - I don't want to stall the user by waiting, but I also don't want to give them time to navigate away.

Comment: Solution used was: if ![vc isLoaded]

Answer (score 0):

Solution used was - if the view is not loaded to do brief delay with dispatch_after before checking again and navigating further.